# Querying complex data types in EF Core with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm using EF Core and ASP.NET Core API, and I have entities that are more or less defined as follows:

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Circle
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MyUser> Members { get; set; } = new List<MyUser>();
}

public class Tender
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TenderVisibility Visibility { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TenderCircle> TenderCircles { get; set; } = new List<TenderCircle>();
}

public enum TenderVisibility
{
    Public,
    Circles,
}

public class TenderCircle
{
    public int TenderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TenderId")]
    public Tender Tender { get; set; }
    public int CircleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CircleId")]
    public Circle Circle { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I want to get all my `Tenders` where a certain user is member of the `Circle` if the visibility is set to `Circles`, so I have something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Tender> GetTenders(string userId)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId);

        return _context.Tenders
                       .Include("TenderCircles.Circle.Members")
                       .Where(t => t.Visibility == TenderVisibility.Public ||
                             (t.Visibility == TenderVisibility.Circles && t.TenderCircles.Select(tc => tc.Circle.Members).ToList().Contains(user.ToList()))).ToList()
                       .ToList();
    }
```

But that seems to me way too complicated, and it actually doesn't work as it throws error saying it is not allowed for the second part where I select circle members and check whether user is contained. Any idea how to achieve what I want more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `ToList` in `Where` condition. You can use `Any` instead;

```
 public IEnumerable<Tender> GetTenders(string userId)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId);

        return _context.Tenders
                       .Include("TenderCircles.Circle.Members")
                       .Where(t => t.Visibility == TenderVisibility.Public ||
                             (t.Visibility == TenderVisibility.Circles && t.TenderCircles.Any(tc => tc.Circle.Members.Any(m=>m.Id == userId)))
                       .ToList();
    }
```

I couldn't try it because it is a bit complicated to reproduce. But please let me know if there is any syntax error